# Finding all possible minimal covers

Tags: database, relational-database, relation, functional-dependencies, cover

I have the relation (A,B,C) and the FDs

```
A->B
A->C
B->A
B->C
C->A
C->B
```

How can I find out what all the possible minimal covers are?

I found one manually:

```
A->C
B->C
C->A
C->B
```

But I find it difficult to find other ones because of the "recursion" in the FDs.

I would like to know how many minimal covers are possible for this relation with these FDs. That would really help me.

Comment: See the comment on the answer to your [other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/250724/finding-all-possible-minimal-covers) on the DA site.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/266284) a question to multiple sites. Please show your research & attempts. See [ask], other [help] links & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Putting words in scare quotes does not make clear the idiosyncratic specific meaning that you didn't write out. PS Armstrong's axioms are "complete"--they generate all FDs that hold when given ones do--a closure. A FD that holds has a pair of subsets of a finite attribute set--so a closure is finite. So you can test every subset of a closure against the definition of minimal cover.